# Grouping mysql if id not null

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this data

```
id | id_att | name |
1  |  Null  | jane |
2  |  Null  | kol  |
3  |   1    | der  |
3  |   1    | der  |
3  |   2    | sol  |
```

I want displaying my data like this

```
 id | id_att | name |
 1  |  Null  | jane |
 2  |  Null  | kol  |
 3  |   1    | der  |
 3  |   2    | sol  |
```

how to grouping data if id_att != null ?

Comment: `SELECT id, id_att, name FROM TABLE GROUP BY id, id_att, name`... If you add `WHERE id_att IS NOT NULL`, row 1 and 2 will disapear.

Comment: I try with `group by id_att where id_att is not null` and then getting error @Roy

Comment: That's not what i said... SELECT id, id_att, name FROM TABLE 
WHERE id_att is not null
GROUP BY id, id_att, name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a `SELECT DISTINCT` here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    id_att
    name
FROM yourTable;
```

`NULL` is treated the same way here as any other non `NULL` value.